# The TDB dataset created in windows can not be used in Linux

Tags: sparql, jena

When use Jena to create TDB dataset in Linux ,the TDB data can be used in Windows,too.But if I create one in Windows and then copy to Linux ,there is no result when excute sparql query.The Java code are the same,and I test this problem in three computers,one of them is  my  PC(I have installed Win 7 and Ubuntu in my computer),all of them can not excute any result.

I mean,the TDB created in Windows can excute sparql query and return resultset,but not in Linux with the same Java code.And the TDB created in Linux,it is OK to use it in Windows.

What is the problem?Has any one know that?

Comment: There are not enough details to identify whether there is a problem in what you do, or a problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that the MD5 checksum is the same before and after you copy from Windows to Linux? Just in case the problem is to do with the copying process. Otherwise, this is a problem that is probably best discussed on the [Jena users support list](http://jena.apache.org/help_and_support/index.html).

Comment: As my partner also get this problem,I mean ,he also created TDB in his PC ,and then copy from Win 7 to Linux.So,I am sure not the problem cause by the copy process.<P>Anyways,thank you very much,as I always get answer from you.

Comment: I think you should really check if files are identical. Please, double check your files using MD5 or similar checksums and let us know.

Comment: Thanks ,the problem is solved,I was not properly closing a TDB dataset

Answer (score 0):

As you said on users@jena.apache.org mailing list, you were not properly closing a TDB dataset. That answers your question.

http://markmail.org/message/sjdvgrcw2b6hn5sf